# How can I rotate a proxy (inside of lists)

Tags: javascript

Here is the example of my python code that rotate the gateway (cycle) and I want to use it and convert it to JavaScript but I can't think any methods (I'm just a starter).

```
from itertools import cycle

proxies = [
    "123.123.123.1:8080",
    "123.123.123.2:8080",
    "123.123.123.3:8080"
]

proxies = cycle(proxies)

for proxy in range(10):
     proxy = next(proxies)
     print(proxy)
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest would be using the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder):

```
const proxies = [
    "123.123.123.1:8080",
    "123.123.123.2:8080",
    "123.123.123.3:8080"
];

for (let i=0; i<10; i++) {
     const proxy = proxies[i % proxies.length];
     console.log(proxy);
}
```

You could also come up with a generator-based solution that would allow writing `for (const proxy of take(cycle(proxies), 10))` but internally it would the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) I got the answer to the problem above. But what about changing only the proxy after every **4 'i'** ?

```
range 1  => 123.123.123.1:8080
range 2  => 123.123.123.1:8080
range 3  => 123.123.123.1:8080
range 4  => 123.123.123.1:8080
range 5  => 123.123.123.2:8080
range 6  => 123.123.123.2:8080
range 7  => 123.123.123.2:8080
range 8  => 123.123.123.2:8080
range 9  => 123.123.123.2:8080
range 10 => 123.123.123.3:8080
```